# How can I deal with this MEF related ReflectionTypeLoadException exception?

Tags: c#, .net, mef, composition

I have three projects, v.i.z. `Shell.Core`, `Shell`, and `Services.Employees`. `Shell` imports parts from `Services.Employees`, i.e. the latter project is external and not referenced in any of the solution projects. As well as `Shell`, `Shell.Core' is also a WPF application, not a  class library. I started it as that project type for DevExpress to include all the correct references for me, as it defines certain shared UI components.

`Services.Employees` does reference `Core`, which defines certain base classes it uses. Now, when the startup application, `Shell`, it should load `Core`, and then it does MEF composition, loading `Services.Employees` parts from a DirectoryCatalog, but MEF sees the dependencies on `Core` and wants to load them from that catalogue, although the host application already references these `Core` dependencies.

As example, when I try composition, I get an error like:

> Exception: 'TypeLoadException': Could not load type
>   'Shell.Core.MappedViewModel`1' from assembly 'XTime900.Shell.Core,
>   Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.

What are my ways out of this? Should I also import `Shell.Core.MappedViewModel`, although it is already in a referenced project? Should I convert `Core` to a class library, so it will appear in the catalogue directory as a DLL and MEF will load it as a dependency of `Services.Employees`? Is there any other way to get around this sticky little problem?

Comment: It would help if you add the code that creates the CompositionContainer and catalogs. Also add info on your directory structure. Are you loading assemblies from a directory that is not in the probing path? Finally what is XTime900.Shell.Core? You don't mention it anywhere else in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like this happened. `Shell.Core.MappedViewModel1, referenced by the plugins, loaded the ViewModel types. Then, the MEF plugins referenced this project, and during composition, couldn't find the right objects. When I factored View Models out into a separate project, referenced by both`Core` and the MEF imports, all worked well again.